# Why barcodescanner is not getting installed? in ionic

Tags: node.js, plugins, ionic3, barcode-scanner, node-gyp

I'm not able to install `ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barodescanner`  or `ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barodescanner`

whenever I'm trying to install I'm getting this error

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barodescanner

    npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    npm ERR! code E404
    npm ERR! 404 'phonegap-plugin-barodescanner' is not in the npm registry.
    npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
    npm ERR! 404 (or use the name yourself!)
    npm ERR! 404 
    npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
    npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
    npm ERR! 404 
    npm ERR! 404  'phonegap-plugin-barodescanner@latest' is not in the npm registry.
    npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
    npm ERR! 404 
    npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
    npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/ashish/.npm/_logs/2020-02-07T11_59_10_117Z-debug.log
    [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.[1]

            cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barodescanner exited with exit code 1.

            Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install without a typo: `ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner` or `ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`.